# How to access/change an object in recycler view holder after triggering something?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm currently developing an app which can detect an asset with an RFID reader. What   i want to do is everytime an asset is detected, an object to identify whether an asset is detected or not in the recycler view holder that contains the list of registered assets (in this case an image view? changes if the asset is detected (in this case turns green) and do nothing if the asset is not detected.

My question is how to access the image view in the recycler view holder layout and trigger the change in the activity (using a certain procedure)?

Here i will provide you some codes which i already made in the project.

The method in the activity for checking whether an asset is detected or not.

```
public void checkData(){
        for(AssetAPI a : assetAPIList){
            for(String b : detectedData){
                if(a.getAsset_rfid().equals(b)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "checkData: " + "detected " + a.getName() + b ); // executed everytime a data is detected
                    showToast("Data detected = " + b);
                    a.setDetected(1); // a decoy to change the imageview but doesn't work properly, explained in the next procedure
                }
                else{
                    Log.i(TAG, "checkData: " + "undetected" );
                    a.setDetected(0); // a decoy to change the imageview but doesn't work properly, explained in the next procedure
                }
            }
        }

        showData(); // set a new recycler view adapter everytime the asset list is changed
    }
```

onBindViewHolder method in the recycler view adapter class.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
       // code
       // code
       // code

       // this is the code to change the imageview to green if the data is detected by checking if the model class has a certain value or not, in this case 1 if detected and 0 by default
       // the image view doesn't change properly, only change 1 data even if 3 data is detected
       if(listData.get(position).getDetected() == 1){
            holder.ivStatus.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
       } 

       // code
       // code
       // code
}
```

I don't think this is the right way to do and i'm not sure how is the correct way to do this. I will provide you with more details if needed and any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: update your dataset and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: create a flag in your model and based on that show or change the image,
when RFID is found make the flag true at that position and notify the adapter

Comment: You need to find out the adapter position of particular APIList which is get Detected. After that call notifyItemChange(int index); by passing adapter position.